# Iterate over List<Map<String, String>> in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to iterate `List<Map<String, String>>` in Java. However, I'm not able to iterate it properly. Can any one guide me?

```
Iterator it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: atleast show what have you tried so far, any exception, errors

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: If list is a List<Map<String, String>> then it should be a compile error...

Comment: @Nizam ok done, have a try/debug now

Comment: You will in general need a double loop.  Your List has multiple elements, and each element is a `Map` which itself has multiple entries.  Thus you need a two nested loops to get at all the map entries.

Comment: @Nizam Please accept the answer, if it solves your purpose

Answer (score 6):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, String>> myListOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map1.put("Fname", "Ankur");

        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2.put("Lname", "Singhal");

        myListOfMaps.add(map1);
        myListOfMaps.add(map2);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < myListOfMaps.size() ; i++) {
            Map<String, String> myMap = myListOfMaps.get(i);
            System.out.println("Data For Map" + i);
            for (Entry<String, String> entrySet : myMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key = " + entrySet.getKey() + " , Value = " + entrySet.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
Data For Map0
Key = Fname , Value = Ankur
Data For Map1
Key = Lname , Value = Singhal
```

Comment: Use enhanced for loop or iterator for sequential access. I would only advise to use `List.get(int)` for random access.

Comment: @Nizam run the above program, the same i have executed and then copied the output, your input might be different,.

Comment: @ankur-singhal my input is like this Received Request for:[{Id=1066276530, Key1=1815401000238}]

Comment: @ankur-singhal I want to iterate that object and get the key and values

Comment: @Nizam did you understood the program i have written, do you find any issues in that, debug it, later compare with what you want

Comment: I didn't run your program ankur bhai. Because I don't require to construct it again. Take that sample input and cast it and give a try

Comment: @Nizam ok i think this is something sort of response string, you need to pars it and put it in a map form, this is not actual representation of a map

Comment: @Nizam it is clear that your question does not exactly reflect what you need. As a matter of fact it is not even clear what your input is. Is it an object? A string that requires parsing?

Answer (score 4):

Forget using the iterator directly, why not simply this:

```
List<Map<String,String>> l = new ArrayList<>();
...
// add map elements to list
...

for (Map<String,String> m:l) {
  for (Map.Entry<String,String> e:m.entrySet()) {
    String key = e.getKey();
    String value = e.getValue();
    // Do something with key/value
  }
}
```

This is called an [Enhanced for Loop](https://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/enhanced-for.html). Internally it will handle it as a for loop traversing the iterator of any collection, or any other implementation of the [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) Interface.

It was already used for traversing the Map Entries in one answer, so why not for the list of maps?

Of course, for nested collections, you also need to know how to nest your for-loops (how you put one for loop inside the other).

Answer (score 2):

You iterate over a list with elements of type `Map<String, String>`. So casting to `Map.Entry` will give you a `ClassCastException`.

Try it like this

```
Iterator it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) it.next();
    for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

It would be easier for you, if you didn't use the raw types `Iterator` and `Map.Entry`. Use generics wherever possible. So the code would look like this:

```
Iterator<Map<String, String>> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map<String, String> map = it.next(); //so here you don't need a potentially unsafe cast
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

list has no entySet() method!

Try this:

```
    final Iterator<Map<String, String>> it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        Map<String, String> mapElement = it.next();
        // do what you want with the mapElement
    }
```

Of course, you will need another loop to iterate over the elements in the map.

Comment: This is wrong.  `it.next()` returns a `Map<String,String>`, so casting it to a `Map.Entry` will fail at runtime.  (The compiler only allows it because `Map` is an interface and one _could_ define a subclass of `Map.Entry<K,V>` that implements `Map`.)