# How to iterate a List<Map<String,String>> and add its key,values in a Java Object

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I have a Java object which have four attributes, I want to set these attributes from result of `List<Map<String,String>>`.

Java class:

```
class Fruit{ 
    private String apple;
    private String banana;    
    private String mango;   
    private String orange;

    //getter and setters
}
```

I have a method that returns data in the form of `List<Map<String, String>>`:

```
[
  {"apple":"sweet","banana":"less sweet","mango":"more sweet","orange":"citric"},
  {"apple":"less sweet","banana":"more sweet","mango":" sweet","orange":"less citric"}
]
```

My task is to map these values to my Java class object so that I can return from my main method, something like `List<Fruit>`:

```
public List<Fruit> getfruits(){

    Fruit f=new Fruit();
    List<Map<String,String>> data=getdetails(returns List<Map<String,String>>)
    for(int i=0;i<data.size;i++){
        Map<String,String> map=data.get(i);

        //Now I want to iterate my map in a such way that it adds objects to my java class and return a list of Fruit object:
        //mapping to getter and setters of my Fruit class

        f.setApple(map.get("apple"));
        f.setMango(map.get("mango");
        f.setBanana(map.get("banana");
        f.setOrange(map.get("orange");

        //But I don't want to hardcode the values in getter and setter methods
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 things, 1st please format the post and 2nd any idea about jackson or Gson?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I fixed your formatting; please [edit] your post to see what I did to correct it.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, i am actually new in it. I am getting all the data, but just want to append it in my java object .

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison :)

Comment: Except for the naming (why does a fruit have an apple and an orange? shouldn't it be, I don't know, a basket?) and the fact that you create a single fruit instead of creating one per element of the list, what you have is just fine, and is basically the best you can do. What's the concrete problem with that code?

Comment: Try this post will help, it solves similar issue. [Iterate over List<Map<String, String>> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041740/iterate-over-listmapstring-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
     List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
     for (Map<String, String> m : data) {
           Fruit f = new Fruit();
           f.setApple(m.get(“apple”));
           f.setMango(m.get(“mango”));
           f.setBanana(m.get(“banana”));
           f.setOrange(m.get(“orange”));
           fruits.add(f);
     }
     return fruits;
}
```

**Edit**: Didn’t see that you didn’t want them hard coded, so you need to have a different way of setting your values. Perhaps make a set() method that has a parameter for what is being saved and the value.

**Edit 2**: Why not just have one map variable in your Fruit class and just have a method to get and set based on keys?

Comment: Yes the problem is that, Eventually i have to do sort the class. Suppose my class has an attribute "purChaseDate", and i have to sort objects on the basis of this attribute. Than i guess map will not be that much effiicient.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with help of **ObjectMapper**

```
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<Map<String,String>> dataMap = new ArrayList<>();

    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataMap);

List<Fruit> fruits = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Fruit>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection.
Directly 
or via Apache Commons BeanUtils ([PropertyUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html).get/setProperty) 
or via something else.